# How convert string with underscore to unicode?

Tags: python, unicode

I try to create array with string elements in python.

```
 a = array('u',["sub_id","datetime"])
```

Python show TypeError: array item must be unicode character

Reason of create array is to send it with request. I use rest API with JSON of some product and send request, but It says this param is must be a array.(tuple and list don't suit)

I use python 3.4.4,How can I fix this?

Comment: are you on Py 2 or 3?

Comment: Strange, when I run your code I don't get TypeError, I get `NameError: name 'array' is not defined`. Is this the exact complete code you're running?

Comment: @Kevin you need to `import array`

Comment: What are you trying to do this for? In most cases, a Unicode string (`u"sub_id"`) or even a Python list of Unicode characters (`list(u"sub_id")` or `[u's', u'u', u'b', u'_', u'i', u'd']`) is probably more useful than a C-style array of Unicode characters.

Comment: Not sure about what your API is asking for, but did you try using a list?

Comment: What type of API is this? Is it a REST API with JSON, or a C API, or what? In any case I can think of, this is probably not what it actually wants.

Comment: (I updated my answer to mention the `json` module, which I think is what you do want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays with the type code `'u'` are deprecated in Python 3, and you should rarely need to use them.

In this particular case, it seems like a particularly bad idea, because arrays of Unicode characters are arrays of *characters*, not arrays of *strings*. You cannot create one which is an array of multiple Unicode strings. If the API you’re using wants a list of multiple strings, then it does not want you to use a Python `array`.

---

What JSON calls an “array” is very similar to what Python calls a “list”. What you actually should be doing is creating a Python list of all your strings, like `["sub_id","datetime"]`, and then using Python’s [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html) to encode the Python list into a JSON document containing an array.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has nothing to do with the underscore.

You don't need the square brackets for arrays of typecode `'u'`; unicode objects are iterable:

```
>>> a = array('u', u'sub_id')
>>> a.append(u'g')
>>> a
array('u', u'sub_idg')
```

---

```
>>> a = array('u', u'sub_id datetime')
>>> a.extend(u' time')
>>> a
array('u', u'sub_id datetime time')
```

This is different for numeric types since they are not iterable, and you need to pass the iterable of numbers via a list.

---

With Python 3.4 version included, I'm starting to think your API actually wants a list of strings.

Comment: It 's not suitable

Comment: Then you should have included that in the question.